# how can get all loop's strings of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I want to make a loop with jquery. but I just got the first string

I made a random characters creator and I have a div and a button

I want to make a for loop and push them to my div,
but when i try this, I just get one created character by my function. I want to get all character depends of my loop's amount.

```js
function randChar(length) {
  var result = '';
  var characters = 'xyz123ABC';
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}


var $btn = $("#btn");
var $con = $("#con");
$btn.click(function() {
  var $i;
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    var $theni = randChar(64);
  }
  $con.html($theni);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="con">

</div>

<button type="button" id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: `var $theni = randChar(64);` There's only one `$theni` variable, and you're overwriting it on every iteration of the loop, so you only get the last value.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and script  - like the button

Comment: By the way, don't use `$` for every variable name. In fact don't use it at all. Some people do it to denote a jQuery object, but you should know what your variables do by their name, so it's extraneous.

Comment: Your code should create 64 characters, not 1 character.

Comment: Juse move the assign to the div inside the loop and append`for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    var $theni = randChar(64); $con.append($theni);
  }`

Comment: yes. its right . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are running your randomizer 10 times, but only using the output once since its not being added to another string.

You can directly append the output of the function to the dom in the loop itself.

```
 var $btn = $("#btn");
 var $con = $("#con");
 $btn.click(function () {
     var $i;
     $con.html("");
     for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
       $con.append(randChar(64));
     }
 });
```

Comment: but one question. append stays created characters  allways. if i want to refresh the characters by clicking my button. what should i do ?

Comment: @Alex, I updated my answer but basically just include `$con.html("");` before the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your onclick function with:

```
var txt = '', i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  $con.append( randChar(64) );
}
```

If you only need to modify the text, avoid using the `.html()` method.